# How to access my running code Thread from a GUI Textbox. C# Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to access a method, and a variable in that method, that is also in a separate thread from a GUI Textbox in Windows Forms.
Every other question people have is how to go the other way by accessing the GUI from a separate thread that's the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

```
public ClientWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var ItemThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ItemRun));
    ItemThread.Start();
}
public void ItemRun()
{    //..
}
public void Return(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{        //need to access a variable in ItemRun() from here 
}
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: What do you mean a variable on another thread, threads don't have variables unless that thread is instantiating a local variable in some routine

Comment: Can you provide some code about what you are trying to do? "Variables" don't exist on threads...

Comment: Make said variable global, so your the scope in witch you want it can access it, then make sure there is no race condition and its thread safe, using a lock if you need to

Comment: You still havent added any code or qualified what you actually want

Comment: i added code, Im just trying to change a variable to the text entered in a text box after having pressed enter in such text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your *Variable/s* *Global*, also if you need thread safety you need use some sort of locking mechanism

```
// create global variable
private volatile int somevar;

// create a sync object to lock
private int _sync = new object();

...

public void ItemRun()
{   
    // make sure you lock it 
    // if there might be race conditions or you need thread safety
    lock(_sync)
    {
       // update your global variable
       somevar = 3;
    }
}
public void Return(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{       
    // lock it again if you need to deal with race conditions
    // or thread safty
    lock(_sync)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine(somevar);
    }
}
```

**Update**

[volatile (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by
>   multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are
>   declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that
>   assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most
>   up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.

Comment: ok this is helpful but what if im also trying to access 
public void ItemRun()
{ using (var send = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {..} }
from Return()

Comment: Then you need to store and copy those bytes into a global array of bytes, or to another memory stream (that you will need to dispose of when you are fin ished

Comment: Since you are accessing it from separate threads, you should probably mark it as `volatile`.

Comment: @RonBeyer good point